# How to send system messages to irssi?

Tags: irssi, messaging, libnotify

I use Irssi together with bitlbee as my overall communication interface (IRC, GTalk, Twitter, XMPP …). Whenever you can speak of something being a message I try to bring it into irssi.

Up to now my setup uses libnotify to forward system messages to i3 wm, but considering the basic approach described before I would also like system messages to appear in a window in irssi.

I tried to figure out how this could work but still lack a general approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script **fifo_remote.pl** lets you send commands to irssi by using a named pipe

http://www.update.uu.se/~zrajm/programs/irssi-scripts/fifo_remote.pl-0.5